# Link boost libraries statically using CMake in CLion

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clion

CLion 1.2, with bundled CMake 3.3.2 and MinGW-w64 4.8.4

I need to get a single DLL in a result of building that no need any other libraries to work. But can't link Boost libraries statically. I bootstrapped and built Boost with corresponding MinGW.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
    project(SampleProject)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

    set(BOOST_ROOT "..\\lib\\boost_1_59_0")

    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
    set(BOOST_COMPONENTS_NEEDED filesystem )

    find_package(Boost 1.59.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${BOOST_COMPONENTS_NEEDED})
    if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
    endif()

    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)


    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--kill-at -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

    add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\\..\\..\\output")

    target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

**Build output:**
O:/SampleProject/Cpp/lib/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-d-1_59.a(operations.o): In function `error':
O:\SampleProject\Cpp\lib\boost_1_59_0/libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:286: undefined reference to`boost::system::system_category()'

What else should I do to link with boost?

**UPDATE:** there is a list of built libraries

```
    libboost_filesystem-mgw48-1_59.a
    libboost_filesystem-mgw48-d-1_59.a
    libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-1_59.a
    libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-d-1_59.a
    libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-s-1_59.a
    libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-sd-1_59.a
    libboost_filesystem-mgw48-s-1_59.a
    libboost_filesystem-mgw48-sd-1_59.a
    libboost_system-mgw48-1_59.a
    libboost_system-mgw48-d-1_59.a
    libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_59.a
    libboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_59.a
    libboost_system-mgw48-mt-s-1_59.a
    libboost_system-mgw48-mt-sd-1_59.a
    libboost_system-mgw48-s-1_59.a
    libboost_system-mgw48-sd-1_59.a
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a linker error suggesting that you are not linking to `Boost::system`
You need to add `system` to `BOOST_COMPONENTS_NEEDED`. Change this line and see if it helps

```
set(BOOST_COMPONENTS_NEEDED system filesystem )
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. Output is the same, also I added a list of compiled boost libraries into the original post

Comment: Could you output the value of `Boost_LIBRARIES` after you change to my suggestion to see what cmake is finding?

Comment: Output as is:
optimizedO:/SampleProject/Cpp/lib/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-1_59.adebugO:/SampleProject/Cpp/lib/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-d-1_59.aoptimizedO:/SampleProject/Cpp/lib/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib/libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_59.adebugO:/SampleProject/Cpp/lib/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib/libboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_59.a

Comment: what happens if you just copy all the boost .a files to the same folder as your source file?

Comment: Doesn't help as well :(